# Elasticsearch filter by nested fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a problem with creating a query to Elasticsearch with many conditions. My model looks like:

```
data class Product(
        @Id
        val id: String? = null,
        val category: String,
        val imagesUrls: List<String>,
        @Field(type = FieldType.Double)
        val price: Double?,
        @Field(type = FieldType.Nested)
        val parameters: List<Parameter>?
)

data class Parameter(
        val key: String,
        val values: List<String>
)
```

I would like to query products by:

- category (for example `cars`)
- price (between 20k $ and 50k $)
- and parameters -> For example products with many parameters, like key `capacity` values `4L`, `5L` and second parameter gear transmission values `manual`

My current query looks like this:

```
GET data/_search
{

  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "category.keyword": {
              "value": "cars"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "parameters",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {"term": {
                    "parameters.key.keyword": {
                      "value": "Capacity"
                    }
                  }},
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "parameters.key": {
                        "value": "4L, 5L"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

- Could you tell me how to filter the product when parameter key is equal to Capacity and check that the values list contains one of the values?
- How to combine many this kind operations in one query?

Example data:

```
{
   "category":"cars",
   "name":"Ferrari",
   "price":50000,
   "parameters":[
      {
         "key":"capacity",
         "values":"4L"
      },
      {
         "key":"gear transmission",
         "values":"automcatic"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Can you share a sample JSON doc?

Comment: Yes, of course. Just added.

Comment: @Ice did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you :)

Comment: @BhavyaGupta I saw your answer, I will check it tomorrow and of course, I will add feedback :)

Comment: @Ice your bounty is going to expire in just 11 hours, it would be great if you can go through my answer, and please don't forget to upvote and accept my answer if it helped you resolve your query :)

Comment: Thanks for help. Sorry for such a delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The search query shown below queries the data based on:
>
> 1. category (for example cars)
> 2. And parameters -> For example products with many parameters, like key capacity values 4L, 5L and second parameter gear transmission
>    values manual

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query, and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "parameters": {
        "type": "nested"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
   "category":"cars",
   "name":"Ferrari",
   "price":50000,
   "parameters":[
      {
         "key":"gear transmission",
         "values":["4L","5L"]
      },
      {
         "key":"capacity",
         "values":"automcatic"
      }
   ]
}

{
   "category":"cars",
   "name":"Ferrari",
   "price":50000,
   "parameters":[
      {
         "key":"capacity",
         "values":["4L","5L"]
      },
      {
         "key":"gear transmission",
         "values":"automcatic"
      }
   ]
}

{
   "category":"cars",
   "name":"Ferrari",
   "price":50000,
   "parameters":[
      {
         "key":"capacity",
         "values":"4L"
      },
      {
         "key":"gear transmission",
         "values":"automcatic"
      }
   ]
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "category.keyword": {
              "value": "cars"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "parameters",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "parameters.key": "capacity"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "terms": {
                      "parameters.values": [
                        "4l",
                        "5l"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "parameters",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "parameters.key": "gear transmission"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "parameters.values": "automcatic"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
         {
            "_index": "bstof",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 3.9281754,
            "_source": {
               "category": "cars",
               "name": "Ferrari",
               "price": 50000,
               "parameters": [
                  {
                     "key": "capacity",
                     "values": "4L"
                  },
                  {
                     "key": "gear transmission",
                     "values": "automcatic"
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "bstof",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 3.9281754,
            "_source": {
               "category": "cars",
               "name": "Ferrari",
               "price": 50000,
               "parameters": [
                  {
                     "key": "capacity",
                     "values": [
                        "4L",
                        "5L"
                     ]
                  },
                  {
                     "key": "gear transmission",
                     "values": "automcatic"
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you need to match any one from a list then you can use `terms` query instead of `term`. Update the part in query from:

```
{
  "term": {
    "parameters.key": {
      "value": "4L, 5L"
    }
  }
}
```

to below:

```
{
  "terms": {
    "parameters.values": {
      "value": [
        "4L",
        "5L"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Note that if parameters.key is analysed field and there exist a keyword sub-field for the same, then use it instead. e.g `parameters.values.keyword`

You can read more on terms query [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html).

Comment: But how you make sure that you are checking parameter values under proper key? How this query will looks like for two car with `capacity` -> `4L` and `gear transmission"` -> `manual`?

Comment: Sorry, one car with two parameters to query by.

Comment: Well that is the application business logic.

Comment: It can't be. It has to be a way to do this on the elasticsearch